# Better way to special case where clause?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a "special case" I need to take into account in a `sql` script. This is what I have so far and I 'think' it works but it seems messy. Its a `sproc` so assume there is an `@empStatus` parameter.  If the employee's `@empStatus=2` I want to return all the employee's with a `Status` of `1` or `2`.

```
select *
from Employees
where Title='Associate' and Status=@empStatus and Department='Sales'
    OR (@empStatus=2 and (Status=@empStatus or Status=1) and Title='Associate' and Department='Sales')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should cover it

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    Employees
WHERE
   Title='Associate'
   AND Department='Sales'
   AND ((Status=@empStatus) OR (@empStatus=2 AND Status=1))
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I was making it more difficult than it was since I was repeating conditional statements.